# C# paint graphics from class in picturebox with mouse click

Tags: c#

I want to paint a graphics object from a method (paint) I created in a separate class (Paintball). I want it to paint in a picturebox only when I left-click with my mouse and I want the point where I shoot to be stored in a List. When I try the code below, it doesn't shoot. Below is the class Paintball.

```
{
    private List<Point> myClick;

    public Paintball()
    {                 
        myClick = new List<Point>();
    }

    public void add(Point location)
    {
        myClick.Add(location);                    
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g, Point point)
    {
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, point.X, point.Y, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

}

This is form1 below.

```
namespace AmazingPaintball
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random positionX = new Random();
        Random positionY = new Random();
        Target einstein;
        int count;
        List<Point> ballList = new List<Point>();
        Paintball gun; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Point point = new Point(positionX.Next(0, 638), positionY.Next(0, 404));
            einstein = new Target(point);
            ptrEinstein.Location = point;
            gun = new Paintball();               
        }       

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            ptrEinstein.Location = einstein.Move(e.KeyData);
            pictureBox1.Update();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();           
        }




        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            gun.add(e.Location);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();


        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var Paintball in ballList)
            {
                gun.paint(e.Graphics, this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
                pictureBox1.Refresh();               
            }                        
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }       
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you know what has to be edited/created. Thank You

Comment: This is full of mistakes.  You are calling `Refresh` in the `Paint` handler - this will cause an infinite loop.  Your paintball class is just a list but you don't expose the items, your ballList list is never used, but you are trying to draw its contents... suggest you maybe tackle a simpler problem and solve each of these as you learn.  You're trying to do too much at once and are making so many mistakes that you can't really correct this code without starting again from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original code has many mistakes.  Let's try to simplify what you are doing and tackle simply storing a list of points and drawing them to the picturebox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    List<Point> ballList = new List<Point>();        

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {           
        ballList.Add(e.Location);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Point pBall in ballList)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, pBall.X, pBall.Y, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have a list, we add the click points to it in the click handler and paint them in the paint handler.  Once you get comfortable with this, perhaps move to the next task in your program and ask a new question if you get stuck with the next feature.

---

Ok, I've got a bit of time, so let's look at your paintball class.  I've renamed it `Paintballs` since it contains many of them and this name is more appropriate.  If you want to keep the list of points private that's ok.  You are trying to implement a `Paint` method in the class, but it takes a `Point` as argument and does not operate on any of the class's instance state - this probably isn't what you want.  Consider now :

```
public class Paintballs
{
    private List<Point> myClick;

    public Paintballs()
    {
        myClick = new List<Point>();
    }

    public void Add(Point location)
    {
        myClick.Add(location);
    }

    public void Paint(Graphics g)
    {
        foreach (Point p in myClick)
        {
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, p.X, p.Y, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have a public `Paint` method that will draw all of the paintballs in the class to any graphics instance you pass to it.  Now your form code would look like :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Paintballs pBalls = new Paintballs();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pBalls.Add(e.Location);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pBalls.Paint(e.Graphics);
    }
}
```

So we've simplified the form code by pushing the painting method into the paintballs class itself.  This makes the class responsible for knowing what the paintballs look like, how many there are, where they are, and how to draw them to a `Graphics` object.  This is step 1 in encapsulating responsibility.

Comment: It seems to not even create a graphics object in pictureBox1.

Comment: @ChefBrohan I'm not sure what you mean with that comment. The graphics object belongs to the `PaintBox` and it is passed as an event argument in `e` - accessing `e.Graphics` gives you the `Graphics` object that belongs to the `PaintBox` and represents the canvas that it contains.

Comment: OMG thank you very much. It is painting the graphics object. I probably need to look again at the process of encapsulation.

Comment: @ChefBrohan Yes, in the second example, calling `pBalls.Paint(e.Graphics)` is telling the `pBalls` instance of the `Paintballs` class to call its `Paint` method and you are giving it the `e.Graphics` object that came from the `PaintBox` in its `Paint` event.  The `Paintballs` class can draw to any graphics object that you give to it - when you call the `Paint` method you have to give it something to draw on; in this case it is the `Graphics` object that belongs to the `Paintbox`.

Answer (score 0):

You're drawing from a list of points stored in that ballList variable.  However, you've never added any points to that list.

Make the myClick list in Paintball public and, in the `pictureBox1_Paint` method, iterate through that list instead of `ballList`.

Comment: I tried making myClick public, but the compiler doesn't recognize it.